# SL4: need to register for a move (or redraw) event on an Item in an ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, events, silverlight-4.0, behavior, attachedbehaviors

Not finding a move event or redraw event in the FrameworkElement class.  And Google not helping either.  So...

I have a custom ItemsControl populated by an observable collection in the VM.  The ItemsControl itself leverages the

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

behavior so the user can drag around the whole assembly.

When the user moves the assembly, I want to be notified by each *item* as the *item* is repositioned as a result of the assembly moving.  So far I have tried registering for

```
this.myItem.LayoutUpdated += this.OnSomethingNeedsToUpdate;
```

but it doesn't seem to fire as I drag the assembly around.

Also

```
this.myItem.MouseMove += this.OnSomethingNeedsToUpdate;
```

only works if I mouse into the item which is not good enough.  Because I am moving the ItemsControl and then have to go mouse into the item to get the event to fire.

Any ideas?  Can I look to some ancestor in the visual tree for help in the form of a OneOfMyDecendantsWasRedrawn event or similar?  Again I am trying to be notified when an *item* moves not be notified when the assembly moves.

Comment: Can you explain the terms "item" and "assembly"? Is the assembly all the items (the itemscontrol) and the items are each of the individual items in the itemscontrol? Are you dragging all of them at once or each individual item?

Comment: @Bryant, Assembly refers to the ItemsControl and all the Items it contains.  Item refers to an Item in the ItemsControl.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writting another behavior for the individual items I care about and then wrote a LINQ query to search up the visual tree looking for ancestors with the MouseDragElementBehavior attached to them.  That query found the ItemsControl since it was an eventual parent of the Item.  I was then able to register for the Dragging event as desried.

Thanks again to Bryant for providing the solution [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461930/sl4-mvvm-handle-mousedragelementbehavior-dragging-event-with-void-foo-in-vm).

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet would be to add the MouseDragElementBehavior to your custom ItemsControl in code instead of in the Xaml. Here is how this might look (using a Grid since that is easier to demo):

```
public class DraggableGrid : Grid
{

    public DraggableGrid()
    {
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DraggableGrid_Loaded);
    }

    void DraggableGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseDragElementBehavior dragable = new MouseDragElementBehavior();
        Interaction.GetBehaviors(this).Add(dragable);
        dragable.Dragging += new MouseEventHandler(dragable_Dragging);
    }    

    void dragable_Dragging(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Custom Code Here
    }
}
```

In the section that says Custom Code Here you would loop through you Items and notify them that they are being dragged.

Comment: I can't mark this one as the answer because of the code behind.  Still I want to give you credit since you got it correct.  Post your suggestion from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461930/sl4-mvvm-handle-mousedragelementbehavior-dragging-event-with-void-foo-in-vm) and I'll mark yours as the answer.  Otherwise I'll choose mine below and close this topic.

Comment: This approach doesn't use a code behind, it is a subclassed control.

Comment: I avoid deriving from controls in favor of extending behavior via, well... Behaviors.  I am marking mine as the answer.  I gave you credit.  I'll be happy to mark your other suggestion as the answer if you post it here.  Thanks again.