# MVVM handling the Drag events of MouseDragElementBehavior

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior, eventtrigger, attachedbehaviors

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461930/sl4-mvvm-handle-mousedragelementbehavior-dragging-event-with-void-foo-in-vm) tells me what to do in words, but I can't figure out how to write the code. :)

I want to do this:

```
<SomeUIElement>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragFinished">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ei:MouseDragElementBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</SomeUIElement>
```

But as the other question outlines, the EventTrigger doesn't work... I think it's because it wants to find the `DragFinished` event on the `SomeUIElement` instead of on the `MouseDragElementBehavior`. Is that correct?

So I think what I want to do is:

- Write a behavior that inherits from `MouseDragElementBehavior`
- Override the `OnAttached` method
- Subscribe to the `DragFinished` event... but I can't figure out the code to do this bit.

Help please! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I implemented to solve your problem :

```
    public class MouseDragCustomBehavior : MouseDragElementBehavior
{
    public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseDragCustomBehavior));

    public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(MouseDragCustomBehavior));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            base.DragFinished += MouseDragCustomBehavior_DragFinished;
        }
    }

    private void MouseDragCustomBehavior_DragFinished(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var command = this.Command;
        var param = this.CommandParameter;

        if (command != null && command.CanExecute(param))
        {
            command.Execute(param);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        base.DragFinished -= MouseDragCustomBehavior_DragFinished;
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And then the XAML to call it like this....

```
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Controls:MouseDragCustomBehavior Command="{Binding DoCommand}" />
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```